# Plain functions (outside of a class) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function

When using Swift, up to now, I am always dealing with classes and their methods.
Is it also possible to have plain functions outside of any class, and group them together in a file MyFunctions.swift?

I would be surprised if the answer was not YES.

But since what I tried failed, I would like to know how I can refer to this file and its functions when I need it.

`import MyFunctions.swift` did not work.

Comment: You can have functions outside of any class.  You don't have to group them together in one file.  You don't have to import anything to use them, they're just available.

Comment: just import Foundation and you can access methods anywhere

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But now I get a weird message that I did not have before (when using my function inside a class): 
Use of undeclared type 'CGFloat'; did you mean to use 'CGFloat'?

Comment: I solved that by doing:
import UIKit

Comment: The swift documentation describes functions as being "first class types". This means that a function can return another function as its value. And a function can take another function as one of its arguments. Also have a look at closures! PS: I can recommend the free book from apple "The Swift Programming Language" Loads of examples and input!